# How to edit a file that converts xml to Word?

Tags: xml, ms-word, editor

I have a document that transforms xml to word.
it starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
        <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" w:macrosPresent="yes" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="yes" xml:space="preserve">
        <o:SmartTagType o:namespaceuri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" o:url="http://www.5iantlavalamp.com/" o:name="country-region" />
        <o:SmartTagType o:namespaceuri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" o:url="http://www.5iantlavalamp.com/" o:name="place" />
        <o:DocumentProperties>
            <o:Title></o:Title>
```

How can I open it to add some new fields because the xml has changed, but I want to edit on the current formatting it has got. Is there any way to visually edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) or [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/). If you don't want to spend money, use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) but the latter can only highlight the code; it doesn't help you in any other way.

Comment: i installed oxygen  but still cant find how to edit this file visually, i mean seeing it as it would appear as a word document.Could you please help me in more details? thank you!

Comment: An XSLT is a "program" which tells an XML transformer how to turn one kind of XML into another. In your case, it takes the source form and creates a word document from it. There is no way to "visually" edit the XSLT program in Word since it's not the output. What you need to do is *run* the XSLT program with some input to get a Word document which you can then check.